# Handling timeouts in immutable classes

Tags: scala, thread-safety, timeout, immutability

I want a thread-safe (immutable) Scala class for a long working task. For some corner cases the tasks takes very long so I want to implement a time-out. What's the best way to implement this in an immutable class?

My first attempt was to use an implicit parameter like this:

```
class Worker(val input: String) {

  def start: String = {
    implicit val startTimeStamp = new TimeStamp
    doSomething1 + doSomething2
  }

  def doSomething1()(implicit startTimeStamp: TimeStamp): String = { ... }

  def doSomething2()(implicit startTimeStamp: TimeStamp): String = {
    ... 
    checkTimeout 
    ...
   }
}

class TimeStamp { val start = System.currentTimeMillis }
```

This should work, but there is still a lot of boiler-plate code with the implicit parameters. (In the real code I have hundreds deeply nested `doSomething`-functions in the worker class.) Is there a more beautiful way to do this in Scala?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like you are looking for futures. In scala 2.9.x I would suggest you to use the akka library for that, from 2.10.0 on there is the `scala.concurrent.Future` trait.

example for 2.10:

```
import concurrent._
import concurrent.duration._
import ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

val f = future {
  blocking {
    // long running task
  }
}

try {
  val res = Await.result(f, 100 millis)
} catch {
  case e: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException =>
    // handle timeout
}
```

**edit:** added `blocking` call as suggested by Viktor Klang.

Comment: just a note: akka is a part of scala since 2.10.0

Comment: ... in scala 2.9.1-2.9.2. Futures and Promises backported to 2.9.3

Comment: If you're doing a long-running operation in a future, you should wrap it in a "blocking"-call so that the underlying ExecutionContext at least gets notified that the thread is going to be occupied for a while: http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.concurrent.package

Answer (score 3):

Use [Hystrix](https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix). It is a Java library which does exactly what you are asking for. Plays nice with Scala and got great documentation.

Example:

```
class LongOperation(...) extends HystrixCommand[Result](
  HystrixCommandProperties.Setter()
    .withExecutionIsolationThreadTimeoutInMilliseconds(60 * 1000))
{
  override protected def run: Result = {
    // your code
  }
}
```

How to execute synchronously:

```
val result = new LongOperation(...).execute()
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about the interesting Hystrix framework :-o. For me as a beginner some parts looks similar to Akka. But I think the Akka solution is more popular in the Scala world, so I take the answer from drexin.

Comment: `withExecutionIsolationThreadTimeoutInMilliseconds`... I kind of hate Java.